# task.run in parallel for c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, task

currently I have the following foreach loop

```
foreach (var formId in formIdList)
        {
            var hasAccess = Task.Run(async () => await _userAccessService.HasAccessToFormId(formId)).Result;
            if (!hasAccess)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
        }
```

trying to figure out how to do more of a task.whenall sort of construct so that all the functions can run in parallel and if any returns a false for the var hasaccess then throw the unauthorized exception.

/**************************updated question for cancellation token************

using jstewards solution below. a bit unsure how to use the cancellation token  (I apologize I'm more of a front end developer so a bit out of my element here)

how do I use the token to cancel the running tasks?

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        var formIdList = AttributeRequestHelper.GetFormIdList(filterContext.ActionArguments);

        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

        Task.Run(async () => await CheckIds(formIdList),token);

    }

    public async Task CheckIds(IEnumerable<int> formIdList)
    {
        var results = formIdList.Select(id => _userAccessService.HasAccessToFormId(id)).ToList();
        while (results.Any())
        {
            var result = await Task.WhenAny(results);
            results.Remove(result);
            var authorized = await result;
            if (!authorized) throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you prefer a "short circuit" version, where the first failure that returns will throw?  Or do you want to wait until all have finished before throwing the exception?

Comment: yeah short circuit would be even better

Comment: @RossBush Why WithDegreeOfParallelism(6)? In general there is no need to specify the number of threads to use, as the TPL will determine the best amount of needed threads.

Comment: @ckuri - You are correct, however, there are a few edge cases, especially when mixing longish database access calls, that can cause the TPL to think there is less work going on and pool more threads than is ideal.

Comment: You can shorten this a bit as formIdList.AsParallel().ForAll(formId=>{}

Comment: @ckuri I deleted my previous comment and added one removing  the WithDegreeOfParallelism as it can cause confusion.

Comment: Have you considered passing an array to `HasAccessToFormId` and letting your database do the heavy lifting, instead of hammering it with single requests?

Comment: @RossBush Doesn't the PLINQ `ForAll` only take an action not a `Func<Task<bool>>`?

Comment: @JSteward - Yes, and if you needed to bail out entirely, the exception would only stop subsequent spawns, you would still need a cancelation/callback scheme to halt already running threads. I misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, it'll throw on the first unauthorized id. However, there's no means here to cancel the other request so they are simply ignored. I'd suggest working in a `CancellationToken` to cancel the other tasks since you don't care about there results and at least `await` their completion.

```
public async Task CheckIds(IEnumerable<int> formIdList)
{
    var results = formIdList.Select(id => _userAccessService.HasAccessToFormId(id)).ToList();
    while (results.Any())
    {
        var result = await Task.WhenAny(results);
        results.Remove(result);
        var authorized = await result;
        if (!authorized) throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you,  I updated my question seeking clarification on the cancellation token (sorry I'm more of a front end developer so a bit out of my element here)

Comment: @BryanDellinger to cancel you would need to pass the token all the way through `HasAccessToFormId` to the actual api call. Then when you want to cancel, call cancel on the cancellation token source. [Some more info](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/)

Comment: oh guess I can't go that route then as I don't have access to the api

Comment: Not the api, you just have to worry about the call to the api from your side